# How to record first occurrences in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops, while-loop

I have two values `b_kills` and `p_kills` that represent a number of kills each team has made, where each of them is updated every ~5 seconds in a while loop. What I tried to do, is to record which team got the first kill (in a game). I tried doing that with `prev_b_kills` and `prev_p_kills` which record the number of kills each team had in the previous cycle of the while loop:

```
while:

...

b_kills, p_kills = ..., ...

...

    if b_kills >= 1 and prev_b_kills == 0 and p_kills == 0:
        b_fkill = 1  # Binary value, 1 if blue team got the first kill, 0 if purple team got it
    
    elif p_kills >= 1 and prev_p_kills == 0 and b_kills == 0:
        b_fkill = 0
    
    else:
        b_fkill = 0.5  # If both team get the first kill at the same time

    prev_b_kills, prev_p_kills = b_kills, p_kills
```

The problem arises when I run this loop while the game has already started but and then, I have no way of deducing which team got the first kill so then, I should also set the value to 0.5.

Note that I define `b_fkills = 0.5` before the while loop, as it is the vanilla value and the value that should stay if I don't know which team got the first kill. Also, I tried adding a counter to the while loop to check if the iteration is the first iteration in the while loop:

```
b_fkills = 0.5

while:
    iter_ = 1

    ...

    if iter_ == 1:
        if b_kills == 0 and p_kills == 0:
             prev_b_kills, prev_p_kills = 0, 0
    
    else:
        ...

    ...

    iter_ += 1
```

I tried to account for the while loop starting in the middle of a game but I just got stuck. I also wanted to wrap it in a function because I want to use it multiple times but as I said, I can't figure a way to do it.

Comment: Confused by what exactly you "got stuck" on, so not sure if this helps...but, you initialize `iter_ = 1` at the top of the while loop which means every time it loops `iter_` will be 1.

Comment: Is there a reason that your game can't just call a simple function when a "kill" occurs that can timestamp it and keep record (it would be a trivial function).  You are dealing with all these issues and it seems a slightly different approach would solve all problems...

Comment: Not possible. I am scraping the 'kill count' so, at a given time, I only have at my disposal the cumulative kill variables for each team. And also as I said, that doesn't account for a scenario where I start scraping the stats mid-game. I think I got it right even though the code is kinda spaghetti. I am going to post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I build on what I already had and it is working properly (so far) but the code is really messy.

```
# Check for the score already in place
if iter_ == 1:
    if b_kills != 0 and p_kills != 0:
        b_fkills_pass = False
    else:
        b_fkills_pass = True
        prev_b_kills, prev_p_kills = 0, 0

if b_fkills_pass == True:
    if b_kills >= 1 and prev_b_kills == 0 and p_kills == 0:
        b_fkills = 1
    elif p_kills >= 1 and prev_p_kills == 0 and b_kills == 0:
        b_fkills = 0
    else:
        b_fkills = 0.5
else:
    b_fkills = 0.5

prev_b_kills, prev_p_kills = b_kills, p_kills
```